# Constructor por defecto se sobreescribe en TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Estoy intentando crear un objeto de mi clase estudiante con el constructor por defecto pero no me deja porque tengo un constructor con sobrecarga,  la pregunta es este constructor con sobrecarga sobrescribe el constructor por defecto? Cómo puedo hacer para crear un objeto vacío?

Este es mi código:

```
  export class student{
    id:number;
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
    address:string;
    asignature:string;

    constructor (id:number, name:string, ape:string, address:string, asignature:string){
        this.id=id;
        this.firstName=name;
        this.lastName=ape;
        this.address=address;
        this.asignature=asignature;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes definir los parámetros de tu constructor como opcionales utilizando "?", tu código podría quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
class Student {
   id:number;
   firstName:string;
   lastName:string;
   address:string;
   asignature:string;

   constructor (id?:number, name?:string, ape?:string, address?:string, asignature?:string){
     this.id=id;
     this.firstName=name;
     this.lastName=ape;
     this.address=address;
     this.asignature=asignature;
   }
}

let student = new Student();
```

Al final puedes asignar los valores de las propiedades de la clase de forma tradicional.

```
student.id = 1;
student.firstName = 'name';
```

Comment: buenisimo me sirvo gracias, tambien encontre esta pagina de ayuda sobre este tema https://es.switch-case.com/54602792

Comment: @ManuRey no olvides darle  ✔ a esta respuesta si te ayudo con tu problema

Comment: Un detalle: Puedes tener valores por defecto en los parámetros: `constructor(id=0,name='', ...) { ...}`. Esto los marca automáticamente como opcionales, no necesitando en este caso un `?`. Es una opción a tener en cuenta si no quieres tener valores `undefined`.